# Display spinner in Visual force page with onclick confirmation dialog

Tags: visualforce, spinner

I want to display the spinner when I click on merge button and after clicking yes on the confirmation dialog but the spinner isn't working with onclick confirmation dialog.

Here is a snippet of my visualforce page

```
<div class="slds-scope" id="scope" style="position:relative">
    <apex:form id="Formid">
        <apex:pageBlock id="PCBlock">
            <apex:outputPanel id="PCResultspanel">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="pageStatus">
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                            <apex:outputPanel>
                                <img src="/img/loading32.gif" width="25" height="25" />
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Loading..." />
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!SimilarOppList}" var="Opp" id="SimilarOpps"
                        rendered="{!(oppInfo.Record_Type_Name__c == 'Product Support - Parts')}">
                        <apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" headerValue="Action">
                            <div style="display: inline; margin-right: 3px;">
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!mergeWithPCOpp}"
                                    rendered="{!(oppInfo.Record_Type_Name__c == 'Product Support - Parts') && oppInfo.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.Is_PCC_Quote__c == true}"
                                    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to merge Current Opportunity with this one?');"
                                    reRender="scope" status="pageStatus">
                                    <apex:param assignTo="{!OppIdToMergeWith}" value="{Opp.Opp.Id}" name="assignvalue" />
                                    Merge 
                                </apex:commandLink>
                            </div>
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageblocktable>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by the below:

```
onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false};"
```